# Cumulative total should start from base value with different starting date

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I am using running total to calculate dollar values over the course of two years. The problem is there are some dollar values prior to two years and not reflecting in the final value. I want to use dates for only two years but want to get the dollar values in the rolling total that are before two years. I am stuck up pretty bad, any help will be much appreciated. So far I have tried this, but still not able to proceed.

```
RunningTotalExecuted =
CALCULATE(FORMAT(SUM(Procurement_Schedule[Awarded Contract Sum ($)]),"#,,M"),
FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Date_Table),
Date_Table[Date] <= MAX(Date_Table[Date]))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace ALLSELECTED with ALL in the filter of your date table.